# Node.js: How to send a direct message in Slack with MS Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, slack, azure-language-understanding, botframework

I am trying to create a Slack bot using LUIS where when the bot sees a greeting in a channel it is added to, it sends a direct message to the user that sent the greeting.

I have looked at Issue [#431](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/431) and wrote a bot. Here is my code:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');
// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log("%s listening to %s", server.name, server.url);
});
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));

// Create Chat Bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, {
    persistConversationData: true // need persistent data for dictionary
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Create LUIS recognizer that points at our model and add it as the root '/' dialog
var model = (omitted);
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', dialog);

// Add intent handlers
dialog.matches('Greeting', [
    function(session, args, next) {
        var language = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'Language');
        next({ response: language });
    },
    function(session, results) {

        bot.beginDialog({
            text: 'Hello',
            to: {channelId: "emulator", address:"User1", id:"(omitted)", isBot:false},
            from: { channelId:"emulator", address:"Bot1", id:"(omitted)", isBot:true}
        }, '/');
    }
]);
```

However, currently when the bot receives a greeting, it gives the following error message:

```
ERROR: ChatConnector: startConversation - address is invalid.
Error: Invalid address.
    at ChatConnector.startConversation (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:173:18)
    at C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:308:27
    at UniversalBot.tryCatch (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:381:13)
    at UniversalBot.ensureConversation (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:302:14)
    at C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:163:19
    at C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:337:53
    at UniversalBot.tryCatch (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:381:13)
    at C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:337:23
    at UniversalBot.tryCatch (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:381:13)
    at UniversalBot.lookupUser (C:\..\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:324:14)
```

(I've omitted part of directory)

I have looked at Issue [#687](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/687) but still I couldn't figure out the problem. How can I make the bot work?

I am using Botbuilder v3.4.4 and Node v4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go here I think is:

1. Save the `session.message.address` somewhere as you will have to use it later in the `bot.beginDialog` you are doing.
2. Before beginning the new dialog, you need to remove the conversation object as you want to create a new conversation
3. Use the address to begin the dialog.

It would be something like

```
// consider making this an array insted
var address

// probably in the function that matches the greeting
address = session.message.address;

// in the step where you want to send the direct messsage
var newConversationAddress = Object.assign({}, address);
delete newConversationAddress.conversation;

// begin dialog with address without conversation
 bot.beginDialog(newConversationAddress,...
```

Take a look to the [CreateNewConversation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-CreateNewConversation) sample. You will see that something pretty similar is being done.