# Error : ChatConnector: startConversation - address is invalid

Tags: node.js, botframework, restify

I'm attempting to send a proactive message upon receiving an HTTP post request.The request sends an address object and a message. I tried deleting the conversion property as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152599/node-js-how-to-send-a-direct-message-in-slack-with-ms-bot-framework). But no luck.Any help is appreciated!

```
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser()); 

// Do POST this endpoint to deliver a notification
server.post('/api/followUpNotification',(req, res, next) => {
  var dialogName = navigation.GetMainMenuDialog("index","FOLLOW_UP_MESSAGE");
  delete req.body.savedAddress.conversation;
  bot.beginDialog(dialogName,{savedAddress: req.body.savedAddress,message:req.body.followupMessage}); 
  res.send('triggered');
  next();
 }
);
```

Comment: What is your `navigation.GetMainMenuDialog("index","FOLLOW_UP_MESSAGE");`? If you want to begin dialog with address, then the api is like this: `beginDialog(address: IAddress, dialogId: string, dialogArgs?: any, done?: (err: Error) => void): void;`, the address should be saved during a previous conversation with the user. Any existing conversation or dialog will be immediately terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The `bot.beginDialog` method is used to start a new dialog proactively, the current dialog stack will be replaced when calling this method.

The constructor of this method is like this:

```
beginDialog(address: IAddress, dialogId: string, dialogArgs?: any, done?: (err: Error) => void): void;
```

And you called this method like this:

```
bot.beginDialog(dialogName,{savedAddress: req.body.savedAddress,message:req.body.followupMessage});
```

So if your `{savedAddress: req.body.savedAddress,message:req.body.followupMessage}` is the address which is saved in a previous conversation, then you can call it like this:

```
bot.beginDialog({savedAddress: req.body.savedAddress,message:req.body.followupMessage}, dialogName);
```

If you have any other question about this, please leave a comment.